# Getting Error while "compser install" in laravel project

Tags: laravel-5.3, ubuntu-18.04, php-7.2

I am new to laravel and i am stuck into the error from last few days, I had cloned laravel project from gitlab and want to run this on localhost i have php7.2, laravel 5.3,ubuntu 18.10 but when i tried to run "composer install" on terminal inside project directory i.e /var/www/html/project_name/ it generates an error while installation.

priyanka@desktop:/var/www/html/project_name$ composer install

Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
Package operations: 89 installs, 0 updates, 0 removals
  - Installing aspose/cloud-sdk-php (1.1.1): Downloading (0%)    Failed to download aspose/cloud-sdk-php from dist: The "https://codeload.github.com/asposeforcloud/Aspose_Cloud_SDK_For_PHP/legacy.zip/abf381316d109316f995d6a9f2c46d83357dd5a8" file could not be downloaded (HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found)
    Now trying to download from source

- Installing aspose/cloud-sdk-php (1.1.1): Cloning abf381316d from cache
  abf381316d109316f995d6a9f2c46d83357dd5a8 is gone (history was rewritten?)

  [RuntimeException]
  Failed to execute git checkout 'abf381316d109316f995d6a9f2c46d83357dd5a8' -
- && git reset --hard 'abf381316d109316f995d6a9f2c46d83357dd5a8' --

  fatal: reference is not a tree: abf381316d109316f995d6a9f2c46d83357dd5a8

install [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--dry-run] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-autoloader] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [--no-suggest] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [-a|--classmap-authoritative] [--apcu-autoloader] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--] []...

I've tried the following solutions which i found from different sites

- composer update
- composer update --no-scripts
- composer install --no-scripts
- sudo apt install zip unzip php7.2-zip
- composer dump-autoload

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sHWrE.png)

Comment: try by doing "composer clear-cache" first.

Comment: Sir, also tried this but getting same error again.

Comment: Please provide the text of error you are getting

Comment: Problem 1
    - Installation request for aspose/cloud-laravel dev-master -> satisfiable by aspose/cloud-laravel[dev-master].
    - aspose/cloud-laravel dev-master requires aspose/cloud-sdk-php ~1.1 -> no matching package found.

Comment: I've used this command "composer require aspose/cloud-laravel
" and get the above error

Comment: Is this library necessary for the project?

Comment: Sometime it will generate the following error> php artisan clear-compiled
PHP Warning:  require(/var/www/html/diesel/vendor/composer/../aspose/cloud-laravel/src/Aspose/Cloud/Laravel5ServiceProvider.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/diesel/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 66
PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '/var/www/html/diesel/vendor/composer/../aspose/cloud-laravel/src/Aspose/Cloud/Laravel5ServiceProvider.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /var/www/html/diesel/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 66

Comment: Yes, Sir it is important

Comment: https://github.com/asposeforcloud/asposelaravel direct download karke vendor mein daaldo

Comment: Sir, resolved by adding it directly into the vendor folder. Thanku so much Sir :)